# Change menu's item place

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

How to change the placement of that item ?

from here: [image]

to here: [image]

PS: The outcome would be a button with the word "DONE" in it.
Although this would be so easy, the main problem here is the MainActivity code which I found a bit hard to tweak.

menu.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_done"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="DONE"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

MainActivity.java regarding the "DONE" item:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_done:
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(actionName) && actionName.equals(Constants.LocationActions.SELECT_HOME) || actionName.equals(Constants.LocationActions.SELECT_WORK)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra(SRC_ADD, s_address);
                intent.putExtra(SRC_LAT, s_latitude);
                intent.putExtra(SRC_LONG, s_longitude);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            } else {

                if (mLastKnownLocation != null) {

                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude());

                    if (RIDE_REQUEST.containsKey(SRC_ADD) && RIDE_REQUEST.containsKey(DEST_ADD)) {
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());
                        finish();
                    } else if (RIDE_REQUEST.containsKey(SRC_ADD) && !RIDE_REQUEST.containsKey(DEST_ADD)) {
                        String address = getAddress(latLng);
                        RIDE_REQUEST.put(DEST_ADD, address);
                        RIDE_REQUEST.put(DEST_LAT, latLng.latitude);
                        RIDE_REQUEST.put(DEST_LONG, latLng.longitude);
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());
                        finish();
                    } else if (!RIDE_REQUEST.containsKey(SRC_ADD) && RIDE_REQUEST.containsKey(DEST_ADD)) {
                        String address = getAddress(latLng);
                        RIDE_REQUEST.put(SRC_ADD, address);
                        RIDE_REQUEST.put(SRC_LAT, latLng.latitude);
                        RIDE_REQUEST.put(SRC_LONG, latLng.longitude);
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());
                        finish();
                    } else if (!RIDE_REQUEST.containsKey(SRC_ADD) && !RIDE_REQUEST.containsKey(DEST_ADD)) {
                        showAlert("Aviso", "Sua viajem está incompleta. Por favor, escolha um local da lista de sugestões ao digitar.");
                    }


                }
            }
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            RIDE_REQUEST = ORIGINAL_RIDE_REQUEST;
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a button wherever you need it in the layout. After you bind the view register that view for context menu:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
registerForContextMenu(myButton);
```

It might be worth creating the following contants:

```
private static final int HOME = 0;
private static final int DONE = 1;
```

Then override the following method to create your menu programmatically:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, DONE, Menu.NONE, "DONE");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, HOME, Menu.NONE, "HOME");
    }
```

With the parameters being:

```
 /**
     * Add a new item to the menu. This item displays the given title for its
     * label.
     * 
     * @param groupId The group identifier that this item should be part of.
     *        This can be used to define groups of items for batch state
     *        changes. Normally use {@link #NONE} if an item should not be in a
     *        group.
     * @param itemId Unique item ID. Use {@link #NONE} if you do not need a
     *        unique ID.
     * @param order The order for the item. Use {@link #NONE} if you do not care
     *        about the order. See {@link MenuItem#getOrder()}.
     * @param title The text to display for the item.
     * @return The newly added menu item.
     */
    public MenuItem add(int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title);
```

then override the following to handle the clicks (provided that you need the same functionality as the one included in your post):

```
    @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case DONE:

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(actionName) && actionName.equals(Constants.LocationActions.SELECT_HOME) || actionName.equals(Constants.LocationActions.SELECT_WORK)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra(SRC_ADD, s_address);
                intent.putExtra(SRC_LAT, s_latitude);
                intent.putExtra(SRC_LONG, s_longitude);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            } else {

                if (mLastKnownLocation != null) {

                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude());

                    if (RIDE_REQUEST.containsKey(SRC_ADD) && RIDE_REQUEST.containsKey(DEST_ADD)) {
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());
                        finish();
                    } else if (RIDE_REQUEST.containsKey(SRC_ADD) && !RIDE_REQUEST.containsKey(DEST_ADD)) {
                        String address = getAddress(latLng);
                        RIDE_REQUEST.put(DEST_ADD, address);
                        RIDE_REQUEST.put(DEST_LAT, latLng.latitude);
                        RIDE_REQUEST.put(DEST_LONG, latLng.longitude);
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());
                        finish();
                    } else if (!RIDE_REQUEST.containsKey(SRC_ADD) && RIDE_REQUEST.containsKey(DEST_ADD)) {
                        String address = getAddress(latLng);
                        RIDE_REQUEST.put(SRC_ADD, address);
                        RIDE_REQUEST.put(SRC_LAT, latLng.latitude);
                        RIDE_REQUEST.put(SRC_LONG, latLng.longitude);
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());
                        finish();
                    } else if (!RIDE_REQUEST.containsKey(SRC_ADD) && !RIDE_REQUEST.containsKey(DEST_ADD)) {
                        showAlert("Aviso", "Sua viajem está incompleta. Por favor, escolha um local da lista de sugestões ao digitar.");
                    }


                }


            }
            break;
        case HOME:
            RIDE_REQUEST = ORIGINAL_RIDE_REQUEST;
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```